# Make the image graph produced by the tool SeqNet Interactive

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

Currently I'm trying to make the image graph produced by the R tool `SeqNet` interactive, I have seen some examples with normal charts using other tools, is there a small example I could follow for `seqNet`? Its a graph with lots of nodes as output and its cramped together in the image.

I'm still searching for a way since the code I used is just an image as follow:

```
p <- 100 # Number of nodes (genes) in the network.
n <- 100 # Number of samples to generate.
  network <- random_network(p) # Create a random network of size p.
  network <- gen_partial_correlations(network) # Generate weights.
  df_ref <- SeqNet::reference$rnaseq  # The reference dataset
  
  g <-network
  plot(g)
```

So I want the image to move the nodes (like alive image) and if I click on a node it displays its info accordingly, how can I do that?